# How to create calculations in alerts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an interactive game and am very new to programming.  I was wondering how exactly to increment a variable and then put it into an alert box. I want to find the calculation of foodCaught and foodWasted and display it in an alert box at the end of my game. Also how do I make it so it is on a timer and at the end of this timer the alert box with foodCaught and foodWasted appears?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cnv = $("#myCanvas")[0];
    var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
    var catcherX = ctx.canvas.width/2;
    var catcherY = ctx.canvas.height - 100; // set the initial location of the catcher's y position
    var numFoods = 5;
    var catcherSpeed = 30;
    var foodCaught = 0;
    var foodWasted = 0;

    function Food(){ // the name of the constructor usually begins with a captial letter
        this.radius = 30;

        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width);
        this.y = 0 - this.radius;
        this.speed = 1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
        var imageToUse = new Image();
        this.width = 50; // default values
        this.height = 50; // default values

        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*2); // create a random number to choose the image
        if(randomNum == 0){

            imageToUse.src = "corn.png";
            this.width = 27; // width of corn.png
            this.height = 100; // height of corn.png

        } else if(randomNum == 1){
            imageToUse.src = "straw.png"
            this.width = 83; // width of straw.png
            this.height = 100; // height of straw.png
        }

        this.moveFood = function(){

            if(this.y > ctx.canvas.height){
                this.x =  Math.floor(Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width);
                this.y = 0;
                footWasted += 1;
            }

            this.y += this.speed; // add speed to location
        }

        this.drawFood = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageToUse, this.x, this.y);
        }

        this.intersectFood = function(targetX, targetY, targetR) {

            if(this.x + this.width > targetX && this.x < targetX + targetR && this.y + this.height > targetY && this.y < targetY + targetR){
                foodCaught += 1;
                return true;
            }

            /*
            var distanceX = this.x - targetX;
            var distanceY = this.y - targetY;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

            if(distance < targetR + this.radius){
                return true;
            }
             */
        }
    }
    // create an Array of Foods
    var FoodArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<numFoods; i++) {
        FoodArray[i] = new Food();
    }

    // get mouse Postion

    $(document).keydown(function(e){ // attach the event to the entire document

        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 37:    // left
                catcherX-= catcherSpeed;
                break;
            case 39:    // right
                catcherX+= catcherSpeed;
                break;
        }

    });

    var interval = setInterval(gameLoop,10); // call draw every 10 milliseconds
    var counter = 0;

    function gameLoop(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); //clears previous circles
        for(var i=0; i < FoodArray.length; i++) {
            FoodArray[i].moveFood();
            FoodArray[i].drawFood();
            if(FoodArray[i].intersectFood(catcherX, catcherY, 15)){
                FoodArray.splice(i,1);
                 console.log(i);
            }
        }

        // draw catcher
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle="#119933";
        ctx.arc(catcherX,catcherY,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
```

Comment: A newbie using object oriented in javascript without knowledge of basic variable storage and alert. It is ironic.

Comment: *"I am creating"* -  I find it impossible to believe that you wrote the above code yet need help incrementing a variable. The code shown already has numerous examples of incrementing variables. It also has a timer, although for your alert you want `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`.

Comment: Please find my answer below and mark it as accepted if it solves your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

After your game has ended, do:

```
  alert("foodCaught = " + foodCaught + "<br>foodWasted = "  + foodWasted);
```

Just make sure that this `alert` is withing the scope of `foodCaught` and `foodWasted` variables.

**EDIT:**

Your game is actually never ending. The `setInterval` that you keeps calling `gameLoop()` every 10 milliseconds, ENDLESSLY!

To keep a track of `foodCaught` and `foodWasted` variables, add a `console.log()` statement at the end of `gameLoop()` function as shown in the code below:

```
function gameLoop(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); //clears previous circles
    for(var i=0; i < FoodArray.length; i++) {
        FoodArray[i].moveFood();
        FoodArray[i].drawFood();
        if(FoodArray[i].intersectFood(catcherX, catcherY, 15)){
            FoodArray.splice(i,1);
            //console.log(i);
        }
    }

    // draw catcher
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle="#119933";
    ctx.arc(catcherX,catcherY,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    console.log("foodCaught = " + foodCaught + "\nfoodWasted = " + foodWasted);

}
```

With this, you will get the values of `foodCaught` and `foodWasted` variables everytime the `gameLoop` function is called.

If you are unaware of how to use the console, checkout [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

**EDIT2:**

I have an idea about ending this game. In the updated code below, I have set the game to run for 10 seconds (just as an example so you can change it quickly) using `setTimeout()`. You have change it to any duration that you want. In `setTimeout()`, I am also alerting the values that you need.

Here is the updated Javascript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cnv = $("#myCanvas")[0];
    var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
    var catcherX = ctx.canvas.width/2;
    var catcherY = ctx.canvas.height - 100; // set the initial location of the catcher's y position
    var numFoods = 5;
    var catcherSpeed = 30;
    var foodCaught = 0;
    var foodWasted = 0;



    function Food(){ // the name of the constructor usually begins with a captial letter
        this.radius = 30;

        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width);
        this.y = 0 - this.radius;
        this.speed = 1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
        var imageToUse = new Image();
        this.width = 50; // default values
        this.height = 50; // default values

        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*2); // create a random number to choose the image
        if(randomNum == 0){

            imageToUse.src = "corn.png";
            this.width = 27; // width of corn.png
            this.height = 100; // height of corn.png

        } else if(randomNum == 1){
            imageToUse.src = "straw.png"
            this.width = 83; // width of straw.png
            this.height = 100; // height of straw.png
        }




        this.moveFood = function(){

            if(this.y > ctx.canvas.height){
                this.x =  Math.floor(Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width);
                this.y = 0;
                foodWasted += 1;
            }

            this.y += this.speed; // add speed to location

        }

        this.drawFood = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageToUse, this.x, this.y);
        }

        this.intersectFood = function(targetX, targetY, targetR) {

            if(this.x + this.width > targetX && this.x < targetX + targetR && this.y + this.height > targetY && this.y < targetY + targetR){
                foodCaught += 1;
                return true;
            }
            /*

            var distanceX = this.x - targetX;
            var distanceY = this.y - targetY;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

            if(distance < targetR + this.radius){
                return true;
             }
             */

        }


    }

    function gameLoop(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); //clears previous circles
        for(var i=0; i < FoodArray.length; i++) {
            FoodArray[i].moveFood();
            FoodArray[i].drawFood();
            if(FoodArray[i].intersectFood(catcherX, catcherY, 15)){
                FoodArray.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

        // draw catcher
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle="#119933";
        ctx.arc(catcherX,catcherY,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

    }

    $(document).keydown(function(e){ // attach the event to the entire document

        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 37:    // left
                catcherX-= catcherSpeed;
                break;
            case 39:    // right
                catcherX+= catcherSpeed;
                break;
        }

    });


    // create an Array of Foods
    var FoodArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<numFoods; i++) {
        FoodArray[i] = new Food();
    }    

    var interval = setInterval(gameLoop,10); // call draw every 10 milliseconds

    setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);        
        alert("Time UP!\n\nfoodCaught = " + foodCaught + "\nfoodWasted = " + foodWasted);
    }, 10000);

});
```

Comment: Don't put it in the document ready. The alert is supposed to display at the end of the game, not five seconds after the page loads.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, but the variables `foodCaught` and `foodWasted` are in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Helen Answer updated. Ideally your code shouldnt break if you are placing this `alert` inside the scope of those variables. I dont know where your game ends exactly, so please add that `alert` in an appropriate place. Or youi could reproduce your problem in a jsFiddle demo if you wish so I can help you further.

Comment: @Helen Your fiddle is broken, see the errors in the console. I would need the game in working state so that I can apply my solution.

Comment: @Helen What are your questions?

Comment: @Helen Please checkout the EDIT in my answer above. If it has solved your problem, please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @Helen, Please see the EDIT2 above. It should result in a complete working game along with the `alert` popup at the end. I have tested it at my end.

Comment: @RahulDesai Yes it works perfectly thank you!! Also, how would you make the timer a div outside the canvas?

Comment: @Helen Not sure what you mean by `how would you make the timer a div outside the canvas?` Please elaborate.